# How To Pass Textbox Value Present In UserControl To Aspx Page Label By Clicking Button In UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

TestUC.ascx Design Code

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter Some Text" ></asp:TextBox><br />
  <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btn1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Test.aspx Page Code

```
 <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControls/TestUC.ascx" TagName="WebUserControlTest"
TagPrefix="uctest" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" >Label</asp:Label>
<uctest:WebUserControlTest ID="ucTest" runat="server"></uctest:WebUserControlTest>
</asp:Content>
```

OutPut:

[image]

I Need ..

Step1: Enter Some text In Text Box
Step2:Then I Click Click Button 
[Note: This Two Controls Are Bind From UserControl]
Step3:What Text Entered in TextBox Is Show In label [Note Label Present In Aspx Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a custom event & you will also need to expose the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in your UserControl, like this.

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.txtBox1.Text;
        }
        //write the setter property if you would like to set the text 
        //of the TextBox from your aspx page
        //set
        //{
        //    this.txtBox1.Text = value;
        //}
    }

    public delegate void TextAppliedEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event TextAppliedEventHandler TextApplied;

    protected virtual void OnTextApplied(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Taking a local copy of the event, 
        //as events can be subscribed/unsubscribed asynchronously.
        //If that happens after the below null check then 
        //NullReferenceException will be thrown
        TextAppliedEventHandler handler = TextApplied;

        //Checking if the event has been subscribed or not...
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void yourUserControlButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTextApplied(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then in your aspx page, where you have placed `YourUserControl` (OR you are dynamically adding it from the code behind), you can subscribe to this event like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        yourUserControl.TextApplied += new YourUserControl.TextAppliedEventHandler(yourUserControl_TextApplied)
    }
}
```

You can use the custom event of the user control in your page like this.

```
protected void yourUserControl_TextApplied(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourLabelInYourPage.Text = yourUserControl.Text;
}
```

And you are done...

**EDIT** : You can rename the Controls & Events as you like. I have used the names only for the example purpose.

**EDIT** : In website projects, if you want to add your user control dynamically then, 
you might need to include the namespace `ASP` in your page, like this.

```
using ASP;
```

And add this `Directive` in your page in the aspx markup.

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/PathToYourUserControl/YourUserControl.ascx" %>
```

Comment: Hi Thank For Your Solution . I Just Now Starting Learn Asp.net So plz Tell Which Name I Should Use In "YourUserControl"

Comment: I Use ucTest for "yourUserControl" It's Correct Or Not. I Got Error In TextApplied This Text Not Exist In Current Context in Usercontrol page.

Comment: You can always name your controls & events as you like. I have placed the names only for example purpose. For the error I have just edited the code. It was in this line `public event TextAppliedEventHandler ApplyTextClicked;` Replace it with `public event TextAppliedEventHandler TextApplied;`

Comment: Now textApplied Error Solved But I Have Error in Aspx Page In Line yourUserControl.TextApplied += new EventHandler(yourUserControl_TextApplied) "yourUserControl_TextApplied"  cannot implicitly Convert Type 'system.EventHandler' To 'Travelmanagement.WebUserControl.TestUC.TextAppliedEventHandler'

Comment: See the edited answer now. I have replaced the line where you are facing the error. You might need to include one namespace in your page. See at the bottom of the edited answer for that!

Comment: i Got Error The Type Or Namespace Not Found

Comment: I have just edited the answer. Try adding a directive as I have shown in the edited answer at the bottom.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44755/discussion-between-gurunathan-and-devraj-gadhavi)

Answer (score 0):

other solution  : create an event in the usercontrol, which is called in the button click.

Subscribe to this event in the codebehind of the aspx page. that way you can update your interface only if a value is provided.

a little more complicated, but you could re-use this logic to more complex control / parent control feature in the future.

i can add code snippet if asked

Comment: Devraj Gadhavi posted it in his answer

Answer (score 0):

This Answer Is Prepared By Help Of @Devraj Gadhavi i Edited Some Code .

**UserControl Page Design Code**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter Some Text" ></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btn1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**UserControl Page Code**

```
 public partial class TestUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.txtbox1.Text;
        }

    }

    public delegate void TextAppliedEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event EventHandler TextApplied;

    protected virtual void OnTextApplied(EventArgs e)
    {

        if (TextApplied != null)
            TextApplied(this, e);
    }



    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTextApplied(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Aspx Page Design Code**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControls/TestUC.ascx" TagName="WebUserControlTest"
TagPrefix="uctest" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" >Label</asp:Label>
   <uctest:WebUserControlTest ID="ucTest" runat="server"></uctest:WebUserControlTest>
 </asp:Content>
```

**Aspx Cs File Code**

```
public partial class Test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucTest.TextApplied += new EventHandler(ucTest_TextApplied);


    }

    protected void ucTest_TextApplied(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl1.Text = ucTest.Text;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method ,If you don't want to expose the Text property of the TextBox in your UserControl Just use method "UserControl.FindControl("Id Of your Textbox which is present in user control")" in your Case WebUserControlTest.FindControl("txtbox1").

And below is the simpler way to  register an event handler on the parent web form's code behind.

Code goes as below for parent form asxp.cs

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //find the button control within the user control
    Button button = (Button)WebUserControlTest.FindControl("btn1");
    //wire up event handler
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) WebUserControlTest.FindControl("txtbox1");
   //id of lable which is present in the parent webform 
    lblParentForm.Text=txt.text; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can achieve this using JavaScript like below (given your code above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getUCTextboxValue() {
     let txtName = document.getElementById('<%=ucTest.FindControl("txtbox1").ClientID %>');
     let lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lbl1.ClientID %>');         
     lbl.innerText = txtName.value
  }
```

Also, from the parent page, you can add a HiddenField and save the textbox value on it (using the JavaScript code above) then catch its value from code behind.